# Trouble limiting data set where a piece of data occurs more than once

Tags: sql, join, count, subquery, having

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, [description], ProjectName, StartOnDate, FinishOnDate
FROM Assignments AS A
JOIN Projects AS P ON A.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
JOIN Positions AS PO ON A.PositionCode = Po.PositionCode
JOIN Employees AS E ON E.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID
```

These are the columns I need but I only need the rows that show up twice. To be specific I only need employees who have more than one assignment.

This next code gives me the results for the repeats, but I cannot seem to join the rest of the tables cloumns for the result set I'm looking for.

```
SELECT A.EmployeeID
FROM Assignments AS A
GROUP BY A.EmployeeID 
HAVING COUNT(A.EmployeeID) > 1
```

Comment: In your first query put the second query code instead of Employees table between parenthesis SELECT FirstName, LastName, [description], ProjectName, StartOnDate, FinishOnDate
FROM Assignments AS A
JOIN Projects AS P ON A.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
JOIN Positions AS PO ON A.PositionCode = Po.PositionCode
JOIN (SELECT A.EmployeeID
FROM Assignments AS A
GROUP BY A.EmployeeID 
HAVING COUNT(A.EmployeeID) > 1) AS E ON E.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will return the project and position of each employee identified by the where statement's subquery.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, [description], ProjectName, StartOnDate, FinishOnDate
FROM Assignments AS A
JOIN Projects AS P ON A.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
JOIN Positions AS PO ON A.PositionCode = Po.PositionCode
JOIN Employees AS E ON E.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID
WHERE EmployeeID in (SELECT A.EmployeeID
                     FROM Assignments AS A
                     GROUP BY A.EmployeeID 
                     HAVING COUNT(A.EmployeeID) > 1)
```

Comment: I even did this and had that result set but I guess I thought it was wrong. Also, the employeeid in the where clause was ambiguous, but a simple [A.] fixed that. Thanks! I guess I was just being silly.

Comment: I know what you mean.  TGIF :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the hard way, if you don't have huge data set:

```
Select EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, [description], ProjectName, StartOnDate,         
 FinishOnDate from (
   SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, [description], ProjectName, StartOnDate,      FinishOnDate
   FROM Assignments AS A
   JOIN Projects AS P ON A.ProjectID = P.ProjectID
JOIN Positions AS PO ON A.PositionCode = Po.PositionCode
JOIN Employees AS E ON E.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID) B
group by GROUP B.EmployeeID 
HAVING COUNT(B.EmployeeID) > 1
```